# How do I send my CLion's output to the Gnome Terminal on Debian?

Tags: c, linux, debian, clion, gnome

I'm trying to use ncurses in my C program, but it doesn't work with CLion's built-in console. From what I've gathered, in order to make the output appear in the gnome terminal, I have to select it in the Configure Debug screen, but I can't seem to find the gnome-terminal file anywhere - the most I could find are the gnome-keyring and gnome-www-browser files. Where should I look for the necessary file on a standard Debian install?

Comment: Why not simply open a normal terminal, use `cd` to go to the correct directory, and run it from there?

Comment: Mostly because I find CLion much more convenient and I'd like it if I could take advantage of its UI instead of having to deal with the terminal each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog

[image]

and change the executable to any custom executable, like for example the gnome terminal and then pass the your program as an argument:

[image]

Note that once your program exits or returns from `main` then the terminal will close as well.

Comment: How do I locate the gnome terminal executable?

Comment: @Panzer Open a terminal and use the command `which gnome-terminal` (assuming it's in the `PATH`, which it should be).

Comment: When I input that command, nothing happens, which I assume means the file is not where it should be. How would I go about finding it in this case?